# Align buttons on ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have 5 buttons align at equal distance from each other on a `toolbar`.

Right now I'm just trying to place them on correct order, aligning them to the end of each other. For some reason this is not working, three of the buttons are just being rendered at the layout start and I can't figure out why.

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#131314"
android:elevation="4dp">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_camera"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/camera"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_ruler"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ruler"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_camera"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_3"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/crop"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_ruler" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_price"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/euro"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_5"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/camera"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your constraint elements to use `@+id/...`

For example change:

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_camera"/>
```

To:

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_camera"/>
```

Comment: No problem.  Your original worked for me with constraint layout 1.1.0.  So, if you aren't using that version you might be able to just upgrade that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#131314"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_camera"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_camera"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_ruler"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_camera"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_camera"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_3"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_camera"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_ruler" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_price"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_camera"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_5"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_camera"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_price"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I get the "Cannot resolve symbol'@drawable/ic_camera'" on every button. But still I can see the buttons didn't change position in the Design view

Comment: @DiogoCarvalho use your icon or background instead of `ic_camera`

Comment: @DiogoCarvalho remove `android:layout_marginStart="50dp"` from first button

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try This code: 
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#131314"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_camera"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_default_event_pic"
                 />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_ruler"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_default_event_pic"/>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_default_event_pic"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_price"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_default_event_pic"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_default_event_pic"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

Or 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#131314"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    >
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_camera"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_default_event_pic"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_ruler"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_default_event_pic"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_camera"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_3"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_default_event_pic"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_ruler" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_price"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_default_event_pic"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_5"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_default_event_pic"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_price" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: The first one worked, thanks!

EDIT: actually it doesn't, because it uses LinearLayout and I can't align them relatively to each other

Comment: @DiogoCarvalho I can't understand "actually it doesn't, because it uses LinearLayout and I can't align them relatively to each other ".. can you give me more detail.

Comment: With this layout how can I have them at equal distance from each other and control that distance? That's my problem. From what I've read I can only control that if I use the ConstraintLayout